# specify order in order BY

Tags: mysql

this is a simple question but I have been googling long time now but no results.

```
SELECT * FROM `target` WHERE `week_id`=23
and `ini_id`=2
ORDER BY `region_id`
```

When I order this query it is either in ASC or DESC. 
Can I specify a sequence for `region_id` like (5,6,7,1,2,3,4)

Comment: What is (5,6,7,1,2,3,4) based on? is it just a random order?

Comment: no, but for that order you can use a `union` or `(id +3)%8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `target` 
WHERE `week_id`=23
  and `ini_id`=2
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(`region_id`, '5,6,7,1,2,3,4')
```

Comment: NOTE: any value other than 1 thru 7 will be ordered before 5.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `FIELD` for that:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM `target` 
WHERE `week_id`= 23
    and `ini_id`= 2
ORDER BY FIELD(`region_id`,5,6,7,1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: @user2300435 -- np, glad I could help!

Comment: NOTE: any value other than 1 thru 7 will be ordered before 5.

Comment: If the OP plans to continue ASCENDING (except for the change from MAX to MIN - seems circular) they can also use: `select * from data order by (region_id+5)%10;`

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, no, but you can get the resultset ordered per the specification d using an expression, such as:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN region_id IN (5,6,7) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, region_id
```

That CASE expression is deriving a value from the region_id. So rows with a region_id of 5, 6 or 7 get assigned a value of "1", and all other rows get assigned a "2". When we order by that, all the 5,6,7 region_id rows come first, then everything else.

The next step is to then order by the region_id.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this:

**Order by Calculated**

You could do order by, but with a calculated value so that you get the order you want.

For example:

```
select * from data order by (region_id+5)%10;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f80da/2

**Using Union**

```
(select * from data where region_id > 4)
UNION
(select * from data where region_id < 5)
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09fe1/1